# What is the context for Glennon's 1956 intelligence gathering trip to the USSR?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, espionage

In 1956, my father, John J. Glennon (Librarian of the Institute of the Aeronautical Sciences, now the [American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Institute_of_Aeronautics_and_Astronautics)) was one of the few fluent Russian speakers in the US, as I was given to understand. He was recruited by the FBI's New York Office by John Connolly to work with the CIA. In November of 1956, my father traveled to Russia after a thorough background check of friends, family, etc. I understood that his assignment was to find out what was the status of aircraft (not sure what else). He spent three weeks there.

**Is more known about the context of that trip and about his project? He never spoke of this assignment. Does anyone have any information about John J. Glennon's visit to the USSR or the name he used in Moscow?**

He was driven around of course and attended a high level gathering on November 7, 1956. He took 33mm videos which we still have.

From the OP's comments:
This is NOT a technical question relating to spaceflight but it has to do with the history of spaceflight. This is a personal question indeed. You never know if someone who reads this may know. I am 70 now and would like to extend the little information I have. I have applied and applied through the Freedom of Information Act to no avail.

Comment: I am sorry you feel this way however, it is the beginning of spaceflight. Yes this is NOT a technical question but it does have to do the the history of spaceflight. This is  a personal question indeed. You never know if someone who reads this may know. I am 70 now and would like to extend the little information I have. I have applied and applied through the Freedom of Information Act to no avail.

Comment: What reason was given for the rejection of the FoIA request? Was there no information available? Where did your Father travel to? What's on the films? https://search.rsl.ru/ru/record/01000580053 This book may have some answers, if you can read Russian. 1956 was around the time where the USSR pushed German scientists out of their aerospace programs.

Comment: Welcome!  Whatever records that might exist would be held by the Russian and American *intelligence agencies*.  Even when space programs find information about their foreign counterparts, they are not told how the information was obtained, to preserve the safety of the sources.  Therefore, even if your father was involved in espionage of space information, the space community won't have the information you want.  You will have to ask the intelligence agencies.

Comment: @Glennon I made a few cosmetic edits to your post. "Librarian for the what is not the..." did you mean "...is *now* the..."? Also, if you would like to ask a question that is more closely related to AIAA, that might be closer to on-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to Space stack exchange. This site works best when you can give a few more clues, though it looks like a long shot I appreciate you are trying all avenues. Do you have anything to link your father's work with "the history of spaceflight"? This may help. It may also help to rephrase the question to relate to the contents of the 33mm film.  I can imagine that perhaps the problem becomes circular if you are starting with very little. Good luck.

Comment: @uhoh - If that **is** the sentence the author meant, I'm curious what it actually is then. Ruling out things it is *not* one by one seems like a very inefficient way to describe things.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'd made several edits where I was sure it wouldn't modify the meaning, but out of courtesy I didn't want to change that sentence without checking with the OP.

Comment: The British Interplanetary Society's "Space Chronicle" had an interesting couple of articles on American Intelligence and the USSR's Space Program in the [last year or so](https://www.bis-space.com/eshop/products-page-3/magazines/chronicle/chronicle-2018-2021/space-chronicle-vol-71-supplement-2-2018/).

Comment: There were any number of technical visits over the years, and most would involve briefings before and after with security folks. On the computer/software side the IEEE has a nice history of computing journal that covers many such visit descriptions.

Comment: In Soviet memoirs can be found mention of the CIA spies during the parade on the Red Square, which photographed the new military equipment. For spies, it was the only chance to make good photos almost officially. Informal photo shoots would end with arrest. I once read a Soviet book about foreign spies. I remember the method of "hiring" students of U.S colleges to travel to the USSR. The CIA paid for travel, but in return wanted students to take photos of military equipment.

Comment: Photograph military equipment, which they will meet on the roads. They had to write down the license plates of the military equipment and the place where they were photographed. But at the border, the Soviet border guards specifically sought out these films, hidden in caches and arrested these "tourists."